# Stripe subscription with angular

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, subscription

how could I create a stripe subscription payment with ngx-stripe on angular please?

Could I manage subscription in the frontend or it must be managed by the backend ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the tech stack that you use, a backend for interacting with the Stripe API is required. An end to end integration can be seen here https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price where Elements can be integrated and you could use the ngx module. Also a webhook endpoint on the server side is somewhat essential for building a robust Billing integration https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Stripe require that you create a customer within Stripe, associate with that customer a payment method and a product with prices. I handle the client creation when a customer completes the first payment-intent. I do this to stop another round trip to the client as I need to store the returned customer ID from stripe.

Can't help any more until you decide your server tech. For the record the .net stripe library was pretty good and straightforward to implement.